# AppBarUtils in Windows Phone bug

Tags: windows-phone-8, behavior, interactive, appbar

I have problem with AppBarUtils, Eariler I have command in my appBar and when it run. However something broke. My Main.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="OsiągnijCelPhoneApp.Views.Main"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

       xmlns:appBarUtils="clr-namespace:AppBarUtils;assembly=AppBarUtils"
       xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
       DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="login"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

    <!--<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <appBarUtils:AppBarItemCommand Id="login" Command="{Binding LoginIn,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>-->

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Margin="25,0,0,355" Content="Zaloguj" Command="{Binding LoginIn,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I use Telerik, MVVM light, and AppBarUtils. I preinstalled AppBarUtils. 
When I deploy my on phone, that I got

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll Additional information: Unknown parser error: Scanner 2148474880. [Line: 25 Position: 29]
```

I think that it is problem with System.Windows.Interactive, because if I comment it, rest run.I debug on arm.

Answer (score 0):

You havent set the interaction triggers. See this example http://allenlooplee.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/how-to-do-command-binding-for-application-bar-with-appbarutils-in-xaml/

Comment: I have still problem. Compilator message is it same as in first post.

Comment: Sorry this had nothing to do with `Triggers`. Line 25 is the `Interactions.Behaviors` child element. Isn't it? What happens if you delete the TwoWay binding property ?

Comment: Unfortunately it not help me. When I debugging application, VS show me  MessageBox "path my solution/Main.g.cs This file has been modifited outside of the source control.  Do you want reload it? Yes, Yes to all, No, No to all ", maybe I remove obj and bin folders in solution?

Comment: Clear your solution, rename or delete the `obj` folder so that visual studio can re-generate it and try again.

Comment: I did it . I have still messageBox with "path my solution/Main.g.cs This file has been modifited outside  ..." . Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you declared the utils namespace?